# Check if files exist in dev tools sources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to detect using javascript if the folder or the files exist inside sources > top view?

[image]

Comment: Apparently none. Consider submitting a feature request on https://crbug.com

Comment: I was thinking to use live http headers to check if the particular file was loaded up, but I thought maybe there was another, better way of checking for the files. I will submit the request, thanks